# Can't get In-App Purchase to work

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

Ok I am tearing my hair out over this. I am developing an app that will be free (with ads and some locked-down functionality). An in-app purchase will remove the ads and provide full functionality.

So I set up a SKProductsRequest passing it my product id (com.mydomain.Myapp.fullversion) and execute 'start'. This does not fail and goes on to call productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:, where an NSLog shows that **response.products.count equals zero** - so problem!

So, stupid question first.

**Q1.** When running my app via Xcode on my test device, does the test device need to have a connection to the Internet (e.g. wireless ON) or is it sufficient that the Mac which is running Xcode has an Internet connection? (Answered: You need a connection on the test device).

**Q2.How do I get this to work?**

I have checked all of the following:

**Have you enabled In-App Purchases for your App ID?:** 
 In the Provisioning Portal under App IDs I have 'bundle_seed_id.com.mydomain.Myapp' and 'In-App Purchase' is enabled.

**Have you checked Cleared for Sale for your product?:** 
 In iTunes Connect I have created my in-app purchase 'com.mydomain.Myapp.fullversion' and it is cleared for sale.

**Does your project’s .plist Bundle ID match your App ID?:** 
 Yes it does, it is set to 'com.mydomain.Myapp'.

**Have you generated and installed a new provisioning profile for the new App ID?:** 
 Yes I have created and installed a PP for 'com.mydomain.Myapp'.

**Have you configured your project to code sign using this new provisioning profile?:** 
 I only have entries under 'Code Signing Identity' (and not CS Entitlements, CS Resource Rules Path and Other CS Flags). It has been set by Automatic Profile Selector > IPhone Developer and matches myself for Myapp, and is set for Debug > Any SDK and Release > Any iOS SDK.

**Are you using the full product ID when when making an SKProductRequest?:** 
 Yes, I am using 'com.mydomain.Myapp.fullversion'.

**Have you waited several hours since adding your product to iTunes Connect?:** 
 Yes, I have waited 24 hours.

**Are your bank details active on iTunes Connect?:** 
 Yes they are.

**Have you tried deleting the app from your device and reinstalling?:** 
 Many times.

An observation here: On the test device, I am not logged in to 'iTunes & App Stores' and when I run the app from Xcode on the test device it has not asked me to log in (I have a test user set up in iTunes Connect and ready to use).  So my app runs, calls start on SKProductRequest but never prompts me to log in to 'iTunes & App Stores'.

Many thanks in advance. I hope someone can help me to get In-App purchases working. Byron.

**Update 1:** Here is some code though I am not sure how much that will help, As I said above it is failing at productsRequest:didReceiveResponse: by not returning any products.

First I call:

```
[[MyappIAPHelper sharedInstance] requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:^(BOOL success, NSArray *products)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"SUCCESS - WE HAVE PRODUCTS");

             _products = products;

             NSLog(@"_products.count = %d", _products.count);
         }
         else
         {
             if(products == nil)
             {
                 NSLog(@"FAILED - WE HAVE NO PRODUCTS");
             }
         }
     }];
```

The code for that looks like:

```
- (void)requestProductsWithCompletionHandler:(RequestProductsCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    _completionHandler = [completionHandler copy];

    NSLog(@"IAPHelper, requestProductsWithCompletionHandler{}, _productIdentifiers = %@", [_productIdentifiers anyObject]);

    _productsRequest = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:_productIdentifiers];
    _productsRequest.delegate = self;
    [_productsRequest start];

}
```

The 'start' does not fail and goes on to call productsRequest:didReceiveResponse:

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
```

{

```
NSLog(@"Loading list of products...");

NSLog(@"iAPHelper, productRequest:didRecieveResponse{}, Products count = %d", response.products.count);
```

And as soon as you come into this function it has failed as response.products.count equals zero.

I have just added the following debug code to productRequest:didRecieveResponse{}

```
for (NSString *invalidProductId in response.invalidProductIdentifiers)
{
    NSLog(@"Invalid product id: %@" , invalidProductId);
}
```

And it states that 'com.mydomain.Myapp.fullversion' is invalid.

**Update 2:** This is beyond a joke now - still not working!

I have followed http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2259/_index.html exactly. I thought that the problem may have been that when creating my in-app purchase I had uploaded a screenshot - but I rectified that by deleting the in-app purchase, re-creating it ensuring that it is in state of 'Waiting for Screenshot' as per documentation. I have now waited over 12 hours for the re-created in-app purchase to filter through Apple's servers.  I deleted the app from my test device. Checked that I am logged out of the store on the test device.  Re-started my test device. Performed a 'Clean' in Xcode and re-started Xcode. Ran the app from Xcode and guess what? Invalid product identifier!!!! **Help, please anyone, I am losing my mind!!!!!**

Comment: @s.bandara Sadly, this does not work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**PROBLEM SOLVED**

After raising a TSI the Apple representative finally found my problem.

Looking at my app in iTunes Connect it states that it has a Bundle ID of 'Myapp'.  Whereas the App ID in the Provisioning Portal which had In-App Purchase enabled was 'bundle_seed_id.com.mydomain.Myapp'.  What was not obvious, or at least to me, is that this App ID is comprised of a Bundle ID that has to match the Bundle ID of the app in iTunes Connect.

The first App ID I ever created in the Provisioning Portal was a wild-card one. When you go through the process of creating a new application, it wants you to enter a Bundle ID that you select from a drop-down list that is populated from the App IDs in the Provisioning Portal. If you select a Bundle ID that has a wild-card it then asks for a Bundle ID Suffix, which is where I would have entered 'Myapp' and then 'Myapp' ends up becoming your Bundle ID.  A little odd as i thought that was just a suffix.

Later (some months later) when I decided that I would like to implement In-App Purchase I would have discovered that wild-card App IDs cannot be used with the Push Notifications or for In-App Purchase. So I would have then created a new App ID in the Provisioning Portal, following the prompts which state that "The recommended practice is to use a reverse-domain name style string for the Bundle Identifier portion of the App ID" - hence I entered 'com.mydomain.Myapp'. I was unaware that the Bundle ID I was creating for the App ID had to match the Bundle ID of the application created previously in iTunes Connect.

I have now created a new App ID of 'bundle_seed_id.Myapp' in the Provisioning Portal and voila, my Product ID of 'com.mydomain.Myapp.fullversion' is no longer invalid and this now appears to be working.

Answer (score 1):

A1. you need a connection on your test device

A2. post some code

Comment: I don't know why you down voted. I answered one of his questions. You need a connection on your device to test internet on your device. You can't use the computer's connection. Please correct. Also, in order to answer question 2 we need to see some code.

Comment: @JorisWeimar thx for answering Q1. My reason for asking was that I was unsure if you had a connection on the test device if that would try to take you to the real App store rather than the sandboxed version.

Comment: @ByronCox please post the relevant code in your question and i'll take a look at it

Comment: @JorisWeimar Code posted. Thx.

Comment: yeah, code looks fine. did you try to recreating the in-app purchase yet?

Comment: See update 2 above. Recreated and still not working. Despair.

Comment: two options. send me your code and i'll replace your identifier with one of mine in the app store to see if it's a code issue (i doubt it). or add my device to your profile, send me the mobile provisioning profile and i'll using my existing in-app code to connect to your in-app purchase.